# Is it possible to run Spiking Neural Network (SNN) on the current von neumann architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence, neuroscience

I am a new to Spiking Neural network (SNN). I read a couple of papers about it. Some of them highlighted that SNN is a kind of a hardware-dependent model that can efficiently work on neuromorphic hardware.

I am not sure whether this means that SNN can't work on von neumann architecture or not. I am just wondering if it could be possible to run SNN on von neumann architecture like most of the current traditional Artificial Neural Network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simulate the behavior of a speaking role network on modern architecture. Many of the features associated with spiking networks, their speed, efficiency, and very low energy use, can be realized only on very specialized hardware. Modern computers can simulate quite a bit, but they don’t always do it with zero overheads.

Consider the content here:
https://snntoolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/intro.html

It's python.  It runs on windows, Ubuntu, or mac.  It runs on VMware which can run on many hardware platforms.

Comment: Okay I understand now, thank you so much!